# Call Stored Proc where Input is User Defined Data Type - Using Python

Tags: python-3.x, stored-procedures, plsql, cx-oracle, user-defined-types

This is Oracle PLSQL Code :

```
create or replace TYPE EMP_TYP IS OBJECT (
  EMP_ID VARCHAR2(36), EMP_NAM  VARCHAR2(50)
)
--
create or replace TYPE EMP_TAB IS TABLE OF EMP_TYP
--
create or replace PACKAGE BODY EMP_NEW_PKG
IS PROCEDURE EMP_INSERT_PROC (new_record     EMP_TAB) IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_MAIN_TABLE ( EMP_ID, EMP_NAM ) 
SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_NAM FROM TABLE ( new_record ) ;
COMMIT;
END;
```

How can I call this Stored Proc using Python ?

I tried Python Code,

```
args = [ '12345' , 'Rajan']
cursor.callproc('EMP_NEW_PKG.EMP_INSERT_PROC', args)

Getting Error as :
PLS-00306 : wrong number or types of argument in call EMP_NEW_PKG.EMP_INSERT_PROC.
```

Please help with code snippet / relevent reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a database object and pass that through to the stored procedure. Something like this (untested):

```
emp_type_obj = connection.gettype("EMP_TYP")
emp_obj = emp_type_obj.newobject()
emp_obj.EMP_ID = "12345"
emp_obj.EMP_NAM = "Rajan"

emp_tab_type_obj = connection.gettype("EMP_TAB")
emp_tab_obj = emp_tab_type_obj.newobject()
emp_tab_obj.append(emp_obj)

cursor.callproc("EMP_NEW_PKG.EMP_INSERT_PROC", [emp_tab_obj])
```

Comment: Tried the same getting same error 
PLS-00306 : wrong number or types of argument in call EMP_NEW_PKG.EMP_INSERT_PROC

Comment: Ah, it looks like you have a table of these records. I have adjusted the code to address that.